# new String(byte[]), String.valueOf(byte[]), Arrays.toString(byte[]), and anyother toString method in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

In java, how can I convert a byte array to java with exactly same size of memory.

eg:

`byte[] byteArr = new byte[16];
byteArr[0] = 0;
byteArr[1] = 1;`

How can I convert byteArr to a String with 16 byte memory?

According to the comments of the java source code, new String(byte[]) "may not be equal to the length of the byte array"; String.valueOf(byte[]) and Arrays.toString(byte[]) seem to return ", ".

Is there any other method I can use?

Comment: That comment refers to character encoding. If you just make sure that every byte in your byte array represents one character in your platform’s default charset, you `String` will have the same length as your byte array.

Comment: You are not putting the characters `01` into your string by assigning 0 and 1 to the bytes. What to do instead? It depends on what you are really trying to obtain (a string of length 16 you most easily from just `"0101010101010101"`).

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? What is your higher goal?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, I was stupid, I didnt mean to print exactly "01". I meant if it can return something like byte[0]byte[1] rather than byte[0], byte[1]. And yes new String() returns the same length, I think it means same memory size. Should try it before ask. Thanks a lot

Comment: I still haven’t understood what you are really trying to obtain. A string of length 16? A string of length 2 backed by an array of length 16??

Comment: @OleV.V. In short, a string of length 16. I was working with a c/c++ SDK by using JNA. The native function requires a char* parameter. They manually allocate memory for it in their demo. I thought translate byte[] to String to keep the memory may be a good idea. Or maybe i dont need to worry about the memory size, instead I only need to pass the size to the sdk? I dont have the device yet, I'll try it after I get it.

Comment: I don’t know [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). I would expect that lot’s of times before someone has called a C or C++ function requiring a `char*` parameter, and that this would require no special action on the Java side. Also I would expect (but just guessing) that the string is copied anyway, so you shouldn’t concern yourself with memory allocation. If you want to be sure to extend an existing Java string to length 16, I would suggest `String.format("%-16s", yourString)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Knowledge learned, appreciate your comments!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
bytes[0] = 0;
bytes[1] = 1;
String test = new String(bytes);
System.out.println(test.getBytes().length);
```

`new String(byte[])` can equal to the length of the byte array, they have the same number of bytes.

Comment: I think you are right. It returns 16. It probably means the same memory size.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may just be a difference of word usage: The `String` does not contain bytes, it contains chars, and each char takes up 2 bytes. So same length does not mean same number of bytes.

Comment: They say more efficient storage of strings containing only characters in the Latin-1 range may be included in a future Java version, though, storing each char in one byte.